# How to override a decorator ( it uses prepend) from gem to Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, overriding, spree

What is the best way to override the decorator from gem to my rails app?

Gem code is something like below:

```
module Spree::ProductDecorator
  def self.preprended(base)
    def base.search_fields
      [:name]
    end
  end
  .....
end

Spree::Product.prepend(Spree::ProductDecorator)
```

And in my app, I have the product decorator (as I don't want to override the complete product class), just want to override the search fields method.

```
module Spree::ProductDecorator
  def self.preprended(base)
    def base.search_fields
      [:name, :description, :phone]
    end
  end
  .......
end

Spree::Product.prepend(Spree::ProductDecorator)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to inherit this decorator class instead of creating a new module, so you should do something like this:

```
class MyDecorator : Spree::ProductDecorator
  #You will have access to all the methods from the ProductDecorator
  #and you can easily override any method that comes with it by defining 
  #it in your decorator class
  
  def search_fields
    #Do your stuff here
  end
end
```

This way you will have access to all the inherited methods from `ProductDecorator` and the new `search_fields` method which will replace the one from the inherited class

Comment: Spree uses product class itself for searches, I cannot use any other class so i need - `Spree::Product.search_fields `  should return `[:name, :description, :phone]`, but that not working. What I found that is that in development environment its working fine, where `eager_load = false`, but in production environment its not working where `eager_load = true`.